# When converting a Fortran character string to a real number the number is different

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I am trying to convert a character string to a real number in Fortran (compiled using gfortran), however, I have found that for a couple of the numbers they appear different when written out as strings and when written out as numbers.

For example, I have the following character strings:

'16072013','22082013','17052013'

When I convert these to real numbers I get the following output:

'16072013.0','22082013.0','17052012.0'

The last number has changed (from 17052013 to 17052012) but I cannot understand why as the same process is used to convert all the numbers. I convert using:

```
REAL :: daymonthyear
CHARACTER(len=20) :: daymonthyear_c
read(daymonthyear_c,'(f9.0)')daymonthyear
```

Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong and how I can fix the problem?

Comment: It would probably be better to read them into integer variables and then convert the integers to real.

Comment: What if `double precision :: daymonthyear`?

Comment: I tried converting to integer and then to real, that didn't help.

Double Precision does make the numbers correct - thank you. Can you tell me how why this works?

Comment: The answer to the linked question explains about _representable numbers_.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be running into the precision limits of a REAL.  Use DOUBLE PRECISION.

Better still would be:

```
integer, parameter :: dp = selected_real_kind(15, 307)
real(kind=dp) :: daymonthyear
```

Comment: This answer should be removed as it does not actually address the problem.  It only provides a bandage until the user exceeds 53 bits,

Comment: Also technically it doesn't use double precision. It just uses a real kind that may or may not be the default